# Python plotting Bayesian posterior offset from prior with x-y error bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, bayesian

I am running a Bayesian analysis where I assume (based on the figure below) a set length as a prior. My model then outputs a posterior estimate for the length. I then input my posterior length +/- 1-sigma into a time model to recover the y-axis error bars.

From the figure below the scatter points are my initial chosen lengths and the posterior recovers length offsets differing by a large margin (but within 1-sigma of the PDF-- the x-axis error bars). The y-axis error bars represent min and max error of a time model which is dependent on input min and max error of the posterior length.

I can't touch the Bayesian model as the process should be considered a black box (i.e. I can't rerun the data locally).

Is there a better way to represent this result? Perhaps as a 2D density? Is there a way to implement this within the standard matplotlib library?

[image: Scatter point= initial guess for length, 2D error bars = posterior length and error of specific time model]

Comment: You can run a KDE on your sample (e.g. with `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde`) and plot the contours with matplotlib.

Comment: @scootie you have standard deviation on length but min/max on time?

Comment: @kazemakase that's correct. The time model is single input/single output. I apply a range of inputs (the length + standard deviation) to return single values of time. In this case the "effective" standard deviation on time comes directly from the standard deviation of length, but the time model does not supply its own errors.

Comment: @VlasSokolov can you elaborate a little more? In particular, what the contours would represent?

Comment: @scootie if i understood your last comment correctly you have standard deviations on both axes? In general, you can say that each scatter point represents a 2D distribution in length and time. However, if your time model (can you show it?) is deterministic (does not add noise, 1 to 1 mapping of length to time) this distribution follows a curve. The way you plot both standard deviations makes it look like there is not a 1 on 1 mapping of length and time.

Comment: @kazemakase The time model is given as t = -log(length) + constant and the original (prior) length distribution is length^2. I obtain the errors on time as t_up = -log(err_len_upper) and t_low = -log(err_len_lower), so it's this somewhat artificial standard deviation in time however, time is the quantity that I ultimately use. I was originally plotting it as only y-errors, however, it didn't make sense to disregard the length errors. I was thinking instead it should be some sort of density representation, but I wasn't sure how to appropriately bin the errors.